# Z3 compilation option

Tags: z3

I would like to know whether Z3 is compiled with _SECURE_SCL=0 or not because I am using it in another application which requires it to be set to 0.

Thank you,

AG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our build configuration does not change the default value of the SECURE_SCL option.
It should therefore in release mode be set to 0 under VS2010:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896(v=vs.100).aspx